# How to select foreign keys from django html template

Tags: html, django, forms, foreign-keys

iam trying to create an add movie function on my movie project,
fields such as actor,director are added as foreign keys.

when i do this via iam only able to add non foreign key fiels to the object.

this is the Movie model

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)
    language=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    release=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    rating=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/poster',blank=True)
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/cover',null=True,blank=True)

    duration=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None,blank=True)
    streaming=models.ForeignKey(Streaming,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ott=models.TextField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

    actors=models.ManyToManyField(Actor,related_name='actor',blank=True)
    Characters=models.ManyToManyField(Character,related_name='character',blank=True)

    director=models.ForeignKey(Director,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    writers=models.ManyToManyField(Writer,related_name='writer',blank=True)
    cinematographer=models.ForeignKey(Cinematographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    based =models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    genres=models.ManyToManyField(Genre,blank=True)

    certification=models.ForeignKey(Certification,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    synopsis=models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    trailer=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is the **path**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Movies import views
app_name='Movie'
urlpatterns = [
    # function based path
    path('add_movie',views.add_movie,name='add_movie'),
]
```

this is the template to add movie

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="user">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Movie Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Add movie title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Released Year</label>
                                <input type="text" name="year"  placeholder="Add movie title">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Released Date</label>
                                <input type="text" name="release"  placeholder="Add Released date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Language</label>
                                <input type="text" name="language"  placeholder="Add Language">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Rating</label>
                                <input type="text" name="rating"  placeholder="Add IMDB rating">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-it">
                                    <label>Poster</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="poster"  placeholder="Add Movie Poster">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-it">
                                    <label>Cover image</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="cover"  placeholder="Add a cover image">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Duration</label>
                                <input type="text" name="duration"  placeholder="Add movie duration">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-it">
                                    <label>Streaming</label>
                                    <select>
                                        {% for i in streaming %}
                                        <option value={{i.id}}>{{i.name}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-it">
                                    <label>Streaming link</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="ott"  placeholder="Add streaming link">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-it">
                                    <label>Actors</label>
                                    <select name="actors" multiple >
                                        {% for i in actors %}
                                        <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-it">
                                    <label>Director</label>
                                    <select name="director" multiple >
                                        {% for d in director %}
                                        <option name="{{d.id}}">{{d.name}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-it">
                                    <label>Writers</label>
                                    <select name="writers" multiple >
                                        {% for i in writers %}
                                        <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-it">
                                    <label>Cinematographer</label>
                                    <select name="cineamtographer" multiple >
                                        {% for c in cinematographer %}
                                        <option value="{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Synopsis</label>
                                <textarea type="text" name="synopsis" rows="14" cols="10" class="form-control"  placeholder="Write movie synopsis.">
                                </textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 form-it">
                                <label>Trailer</label>
                                <input type="text" name="trailer"  placeholder="Add trailer link.">
                            </div>




                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left:30%;">
                                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add movie">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

this is the add movie function in **views.py**

```
@login_required
def add_movie(request):
    str=Streaming.objects.all()
    act=Actor.objects.all()
    dir=Director.objects.all()
    wri=Writer.objects.all()
    cin=Cinematographer.objects.all()
    cer=Certification.objects.all()
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST['name']
        slug = (name.replace((' ' or ':'),'-')).lower()
        year=request.POST['year']
        release=request.POST['release']
        language=request.POST['language']
        rating=request.POST['rating']
        poster=request.FILES.get('poster')
        cover=request.FILES.get('cover')
        duration=request.POST['duration']
        streaming=request.POST.get('{{i.id}}')
        ott=request.POST.get('ott')

        # actors=request.POST.getlist('{{i.id}}')
        # writers=request.POST.getlist('{{i.id}}')

        cinematographer=request.POST.get('{{c.id}}')
        director=request.POST.get('{{d.id}}')
        trailer=request.POST['trailer']
        synopsis=request.POST['synopsis']
        # for actor in actors:
        #     for writer in writers:
        #         movie=Movie.objects.create(user=request.user,name=name,year=year,release=release,
        #                                language=language,rating=rating,trailer=trailer,
        #                                poster=poster,cover=cover,duration=duration,
        #                                streaming=streaming,ott = ott,
        #                                actors=actor,writers=writer,
        #                                director=director,cinematographer=cinematographer,
        #                                    synopsis=synopsis,)
        #         movie.save()
        movie = Movie.objects.create(user=request.user,name=name,slug=slug,year=year, release=release,
                                       language=language,rating=rating,trailer=trailer,
                                       poster=poster,cover=cover,duration=duration,
                                       streaming=streaming,ott = ott,
                                       # actors=actor,writers=writer,
                                       director__id=director,cinematographer__id=cinematographer,
                                           synopsis=synopsis,)
        movie.save()
        return redirect('Movie:view_movies')
    else:
        pass
    return render(request,'add_movie.html',{'streaming':str,'certification':cer,
                                            'actors':act,'director':dir,'writers':wri,
                                            'cinematographer':cin})
```

[like shown in this pic, id's are added on the foreign key fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLog5.png)
non foreign keys are being added successfully but not the foreign key ones, what should i do?

Comment: You might want to look into using django's [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)-classes